# PHP - Declare function in class based on condition

Tags: php, function, class, conditional-statements, declare

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
class Test {
    if(!empty($somevariable)) {
        public function somefunction() {

        }
    }
}
```

I know this might not be best practice, but I need to do this for a very specific problem I have, so is there anyway to do it?

I just want that function to be included in the class if that variable (which is tied to a URL param) is not empty.  As it is written now, I get Error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Thanks!

Comment: `I need to do this for a very specific problem I have` - you are **welcome** to express your very specific problem here and get the **proper** solution. It would be way better than trying to get help in moving a square wheel you invented. To let you know, most of "very specific problems" turns out to be simple and trivial cases that have commonplace solutions.

Comment: Call that function when that required variable is not empty. OR add that IF condition in the function, and that function code will run when that required variable is not empty.

Comment: I will try posting the specific problem, probably a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the your specific use case, and I don't have enough info to give a specific answer, but I can think of one possible fix.

Extend the class, using an if statement. Put everything except the one function in `AbstractTest`.

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractTest 
{
    // Rest of your code in here
}

if (!empty($somevariable)) {
    class Test extends AbstractTest {
        public function somefunction() {

        }
    }
} else {
    class Test extends AbstractTest { }
}
```

Now, the class `Test` only has the method `somefunction` if `$somevariable` isn't empty. Otherwise it directly extends `AbstractTest` and doesn't add the new method.

Comment: This worked, but I ended up fixing the core problem anyway.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Call the required function if the variable is not empty.

```
<?php
    class Test {
        public function myFunct() {
            //Function description
        }
    }
    $oTest = new Test();
    if(!empty($_GET['urlParam'])) {
        oTest->myFunc();
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I only get the desired result when this method exists in the class or not, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
    public function somefunction() {

    }
}
```

is all you need actually.

Please note that a function inside a class is called 'method'.

Comment: Thanks for the lingo lesson (Not being sarcastic, I really need to leran it), however that solution doesn't work for me, because I need the function to exist or not in order to get my desired result.

Comment: @user2278120 - it shouldn't make a difference if the function _exists_ or not. A function should only have an effect if it's being called somewhere. Otherwise, it's a block of code that does nothing.

Comment: @user2278120 Ever considered having the method as exampled here, and then from PHP `if (empty($var)){ $Class->method(); }` out of the class scope? so then you only call it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot have a condition out of the method in class scope (if that flows)

```
Class Test {
 if (empty($Var)){
    public function Test_Method (){

    }
  }

}
```

Will not work. Why not have it constantly exisisting but only call the method when it's needed?

Example:

```
Class Test { 
  public function Some_Method(){
    return 23094; // Return something for example purpose
  }

}
```

Then from your PHP:

```
$Var = ""; // set an empty string
$Class = new Test();

if (empty($Var)){
  echo $Class->Some_Method(); // Will output if $Var is empty 

}
```

---

Perhaps you trying to validate a string within OOP scope, then take this example:

```
 Class New_Test {
     public $Variable; // Set a public variable 
    public function Set(){
      $This->Variable = "This is not empty"; // When calling, $this->variable will not be empty
    }
    public function Fail_Safe(){
      return "something"; // return a string
    }
  }
```

Then out of Scope:

```
  $Class = new New_Test();
  if (empty($Class->Variable)){
     $Class->Fail_Safe(); 
   } // Call failsafe if the variable in OOP scope is empty
```